# Grab favicon.ico using Google Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

Where can I grab the favicon of a website using Google Chrome dev tools. I have access to the resources (html, css, js, images, etc.) but I cannot find the favicon.

Where is the favicon hidden in the Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I had the same issue to an HTML page, then I realised the favicon need not be explicitly specified.  Instead, the browser was auto-magically reading `/favicon.ico`.  Ref: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can sometimes be a little bit tedious to find the “shortcut icon” link in the HTML. 
Another approach is to create an Internet shortcut (i.e., a “Favorite” in IE, a.k.a. a “Bookmark”) and open it with Notepad:

> `[DEFAULT]`
>       `BASEURL=http://superuser.com/questions/532616/grab-favicon-ico-…`
>       `[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]`
>       `Prop3=19,2`
>       `[InternetShortcut]`
>       `URL=http://superuser.com/questions/532616/grab-favicon-ico-using-google-…`
>       `IDList=`
>   **`->  IconFile=http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico`**
>       `IconIndex=1`

The IconFile  and IconIndex are usually at the end.

Comment: How can I open one of my favourite bar sites in a text editor like this?

Comment: Try this: start Notepad, minimize it, drag the favorite to the Notepad task button on the taskbar (do not drop it there) and wait for the Notepad window to reopen, then drag into the open window and drop it there.

Comment: Thanks Scott, sadly on mac I use textedit / xcode / sublime to edit code, and performing your suggestion basically just seems to paste the link of the favourite site. Hopefully there is a way!

Comment: I know that the asker accepted this answer, but it does not answer the question asked, which was was explicit about "using Chrome dev tools". This is also only helpful in the case that the user's OS is Windows.

Answer (score 53):

Here's a tool that's actually part of Google Chrome (as requested in the question), and works for sites that require a login.

In the address bar, enter `chrome://favicon/`, followed by the url.

For example, `chrome://favicon/https://example.com/private-page.html`

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/981361)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer to my mind,..

Comment: Also works with Microsoft Edge: edge://favicon/https://example.com

Comment: I created an account here just to upvote this

Comment: Really cool, is there a way to specify the size? Currently it renders only a 16px icon

Answer (score 18):

You can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to **view source** and look for the favicon in the code (`<link rel="shortcut icon"`). It's usually in the top of the HTML source file, since it's inside the `<head>`.

For this page, it's in the 7th line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Grab favicon.ico using Google Chrome dev tools - Super User</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Why is it not in "Resources", with all the other images?

Comment: @randomblue Where should it be? under *Frames > superuser.com > Images*?

Comment: Yes, or somewhere thereabouts in the "Resources" pane.

Comment: This doesn't work reliably. There are multiple ways of specifying a favicon; a `<link>` element is only one of them.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the power of google to do this:

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.de

Replacing the domain name above will grab the favicon for that given domain.

---

You can also use this variant:

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F

that will get the favicon for any url.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work for all URLs. In particular, I've not managed to get it to work for any variant I tried of https://www.pactcoffee.com.

Comment: @me_and `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=media.pactcoffee.com/` ended up working.  I guess it didn't work on the original since it was getting the favicon from a different subdomain.

Answer (score 13):

Use Chrome Dev Tools Network tab.
Filter by favicon
Reload the page with Shift+F5
You will get the icon regardless it was loaded with link or from default location

Comment: I believe this is by far the easiest method in 2019. This answer should really be ranked higher.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just right click on the page and select  `inspect element`? That gives you the html code of the page and the favicon is listed there. Just click on the link.

Example http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico

Comment: on pages where it is explicitly linked. If the page does *not* specify, the web browser will try the default location of `/favicon.ico`, which doesn't log in the resources or show on the network traffic in Chrome

Comment: @frumbert FYI, Chrome will log getting the default `/favicon.ico` file in the network recording tab. You can filter for 'favicon' in there to see it being retrieved.