# Is there a way to create a URL shortcut on the desktop with the favicon of a website?

Tags: firefox, url, xfce, launcher, favicon

I would like to add a URL shorcut on my desktop. I use Xfce. I would like a script or trick that would give me the favicon of the website URL paste in the shorcut.

Before this, when I was using Chromium, I was able to do that by clicking the 3 dots, then going for more tools, and to add to desktop.

But now (since I'm using Firefox), I can't do that. I managed to have a URL shortcut, but I don't have the favicon with it. I would like a way to have it included with my URL launcher.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a possibility to download the favicon file on your computer and use it as icon for a shortcut.

1. [How to download favicon from website?](https://superuser.com/questions/157925/how-to-download-favicon-from-website)

   > Studiohack has the "thorough" approach but heres a short hack:
   >
   > 1. Enter the domain name like `https://superuser.com/`(must end with '/')
   > 2. Add `favicon.ico` to the end
   > 3. Press enter (this should be in the URL: `https://superuser.com/favicon.ico`)
   > 4. Right click on the image and click "save image as"

   -- Quoted from answered Jun 29 '10 at 2:34 by wag2639
2. [Changing desktop icons](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7587)

   > If you right-click the desktop icon and choose "properties", you will notice a picture of the current icon on the General tab. Click on that image and select the icon you want.

   -- Quoted from thread post 2012-11-12 12:41:03 by ToZ (Moderator)

Comment: It's better you visit [https://superuser.com/questions/157925/how-to-download-favicon-from-website](https://superuser.com/questions/157925/how-to-download-favicon-from-website), and one of the several answers will surely help you find the way to get the desired icon.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a url shortcut in your desktop by this way
right click on your desktop - new - shortcut - copy your target url and past it in location dialog - and then type a name for it 
that's it